# How to selectall or unselect all elements

Tags: javascript

I made a select all box successfully, but I have another question.

How do I make it unselected too?

Here is my javascript code:

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tbl1"); 
var tab2 = document.getElementById("tbl2");
var tab3 = document.getElementById("tbl3");
var tab4 = document.getElementById("tbl4");
var tab5 = document.getElementById("tbl5");
var tab6 = document.getElementById("tbl6");
var tab7 = document.getElementById("tbl7");
var tab8 = document.getElementById("tbl8");
var tab9 = document.getElementById("tbl9");
var elems = document.getElementById("checkall");


if (elems.checked == true) {

    tab1.checked = true;
    tab2.checked = true;
    tab3.checked = true;
    tab4.checked = true;
    tab5.checked = true;
    tab6.checked = true;
    tab7.checked = true;
    tab8.checked = true;
    tab9.checked = true;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `if (elems.checked == false) {

    tab1.checked = false;
    tab2.checked = false;
    tab3.checked = false;
    tab4.checked = false;
    tab5.checked = false;
    tab6.checked = false;
    tab7.checked = false;
    tab8.checked = false;
    tab9.checked = false;
}`

Comment: or just change the logic to `tab1.checked = elems.checked;` etc...

Comment: @undone   i copy and paste what u write but it still select all but cannot unselect

Comment: @dc5   how to write it?   please give me a detail  thx~

Comment: Luk - you already have the code posted.  Just change where it says `= true;` to `= elems.checked;`

Comment: it's work!    thx dc5 and undone~

Answer (score 4):

Give a common class name for your child checkboxes, for example `child-selector`:

```
var checked = document.getElementById("checkall").checked;
var childElems = document.getElementsByClassName('child-selector');

for(var i=0; i< childElems.length; i++){
    childElems[i].checked = checked;
}
```

Comment: FYI: IE does **NOT** support **getElementsByClassName**!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl1" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl2" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl3" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl4" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl5" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl6" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl7" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl8" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="tbl9" /><br />
 <input type="checkbox"  id="checkall"  onclick="selectDeselect();"    />


 <script>
        function selectDeselect(){
            var elems = document.getElementById("checkall");
            for(var i = 1;i<=9;i++){
                tab = document.getElementById("tbl" + i);
                tab.checked = elems.checked;
            }

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to make this as more simple

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_all" onclick='check_uncheck();'/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tab[]" id="tbl1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tab[]" id="tbl2" />
    <script>
    function check_uncheck() {
        jQuery("[name='tab[]']").prop('checked', $('#check_all').prop('checked'));
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: If you want to put something in code block, select your code and press CTRL + K.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkAll = elems.checked;
tab1.checked = checkAll;
tab2.checked = checkAll;
tab3.checked = checkAll;
tab4.checked = checkAll;
tab5.checked = checkAll;
tab6.checked = checkAll;
tab7.checked = checkAll;
tab8.checked = checkAll;
tab9.checked = checkAll;
```

Or you can give a name to these checkboxes, document.getElementsByName will return the collection of elements which contain tab1 to tab9. Then you can use a for loop to assign the property.
Hope it's helpful.